# OnClick button event triggered during loading after onResume

Tags: android, button, click, clickable, onresume

I got a weird problem with one of my Android app.
I will explain myself :

- I have a SplashScreen (sort of) which is an activity. Basically, it stays 1 second and after this time a handler is called. This handler launches my `HomeActivity`, which extends `RoboActivity` (Roboguice API).
- During this launch, I see in my stack trace that Roboguice is initializing, and my class too. So it takes 1-2 seconds more to launch the `HomeActivity` (after the 1 second wait of the SplashScreen).
- So basically, this is here that I got a problem. During this 1-2 seconds of loading, the SplashScreen is the one showing in front, and the `HomeActivity` only appears after this 2 seconds. If the user clicks, during these seconds, on the screen, it will be the `HomeActivity` that will trigger the event. It means that if you click on the SplashScreen, and you wait, when the `HomeActivity` will show, you will hear a click sound and the button, located where the user clicked, will trigger.

I find it very disturbing for the user. So, at the moment, I tried to :

- Deactivate the buttons in the xml layout by adding

  ```
              android:enabled="false"
              android:clickable="false"
  ```
- Reactivate the buttons by adding in the onResume function :

  ```
  button.setEnabled(true);
  button.setClickable(true);
  ```
- I see in the stacktrace that the `OnClickListener` is triggered just after the `onResume`. So at this moment, the buttons are re-enabled and so it clicks. I tried with postOnResume too, it doesn't work either.

Did you experienced the same behavior that I have now ?
Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: How do you launch real home activity from your splashscreen?   busy waiting in onRFesume() / onCreate() ?

Comment: I use this to launch my home from the splash :

Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();

Yes there is some long instanciation on the onCreate method of my home (but I can't do it in a thread).

Comment: Show surrounding code from your splash activity in question body -  comments do not allow formatting